# Why doesn't main() function return float value?

Tags: c, return, program-entry-point

I am writing a program in C that is supposed to return the float value `3.2058` after the function `averagerOfFiveFloats()` is called. The problem is when the code compiles and the IDE opens the executable file, the value returned is `1067450368`. Why is this occurring? I made sure the variable types were correct and that both functions had a float return type.

The program takes five float values in the main function and then the function `averagerOfFiveFloats()` function is called within the main. The function `averagerOfFiveFloats()` takes the five float values, adds them together, divides the total by 5, and then returns the value.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float a, b, c, d, e;

float averagerOfFiveFloats(float num1, float num2, float num3, float num4, 
float num5);

float main (void) {

    a = 1.25;

    b = 4.45;

    c = 3.45;

    d = 1.11;

    e = 5.769;

    return averagerOfFiveFloats(a, b, c, d, e);

}


float averagerOfFiveFloats(float num1, float num2, float num3, float num4, 
float num5) {

    float addition = 0;

    addition = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5;

    float divider = 0;

    divider = addition / 5;

    return divider;


}
```

Comment: return type of `main` is `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are attempting to return a `float` from `main`.

The function main can return only an `int`.

Instead you can print your result as

```
printf("%f", averagerOfFiveFloats(a, b, c, d, e));
```

and that produces the correct result.

Also, the real average of your numbers cannot be `16.029` since all the numbers are less than that.

Answer (score 1):

`main` must return an `int` and not a float. You probably get a warning for this while you compile. Warnings are generally errors in C, so you should strive to have warning free code.

Thus what you see is that your `float` is silently converted to an `int`. If you do `printf("%f", averageOfFive(a, b, c, d, e))`you will see the output you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the right code ! you can't return a float in main :)

I also changed the syntax it's easier to read/understand :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

float averagerOfFiveFloats(float num1, float num2, float num3, float num4,
                           float num5) {
  float addition = 0;
  float divider = 0;

  addition = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5;
  divider = addition / 5;

  return divider;

}

int     main (void) {

  float a = 1.25;
  float b = 4.45;
  float c = 3.45;
  float d = 1.11;
  float e = 5.769;

  float divider = averagerOfFiveFloats(a, b, c, d, e);
  printf("divider = %f\n", divider);
  return (0);
}
```