# How can we declare short int as the return type in main function of C++?

Tags: c++

I am always returning a value of 0 from the main function. I was wondering if we could change the return type of the C++ main method to `short int`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

short int main() {
     cout << "Hello World" << endl;
     return 0;
}
```

Something like this, but the above code returns an error saying that the return type should be 'int'. Can someone please guide me?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  How would this change or benefit your program?

Comment: Nope, `main` is [specified](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) to return an `int`, anything else is undefined behaviour if it even compiles. The return value is probably stored in an `int` sized register anyway so making it smaller won't improve performance

Comment: You cannot change the return type of `main`. If you are under the impression that this would have some kind of memory or performance benefit: It doesn't.

Comment: [Why doesn't main() function return float value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46335588/995714), [What happens if main() does not return an int value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844915/995714)

Comment: @DrewDormann I was thinking if it could affect some performance as int is 4 bytes and short int is 2 bytes.

Comment: @prasadthx Why are you concerned about performance if the program is exiting from `main`?  Also, if there as a performance "hit", how big would you think it would be?  It probably would be next to nothing, if any at all.

Comment: The value returned from `main()` is handed over to the Operating System.  So, the Operating System should be complaining if the integer is too big.

Comment: Personally I restrict my return values to [0, 255], EXIT_FAILURE, and EXIT_SUCCESS.